# How to build a dependency when running an Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

In the company where I work we have several Angular projects, each one having a common project as a dependency in the `package.json`. This common project contains common components or pipes.

Whenever we need to modify a component of the common project we have to run `npm run packagr` and then `npm publish` from the `dist` folder. The common project is then deployed in a nexus repository from which each projects that requires it download the dependency with a `npm install`.

I joined the company when this structure was already running. This process bothers me and pushes me to look for a different solution to run (or compile) the common project together with the primary project at the `npm start` action.

I found possible way by reading the Angular documentation on [libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), but I'm not that experienced in Angular and as far as i understand project and library should be in the same folder.

In our structure, both the projects and the common project are located in different folders each linked to its own git repository.

When a I work on a Java project, Eclipse takes care of compiling the dependencies (previously imported in the workspace) for me by reading the pom.xml.
Is there any way to get the same result when I run `npm install` of a project, my dependencies are also built?